# Comparing two images based on shape and color

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently working on a python script where i compare a image (screenshot) which i take then crop it around my mouse. Then compare this image to a 'library / database' of images in a folder, then it returns the most similar image and finds the correct data for that image which i have created a Json database for.

Basically I'm trying to find out what a specific item does in the popular game 'The Binding Of Isaac'. I capture an image from the screen and as said compare it to a library of images. Then search the `.json` database for the name of that image and find out what it does. The method I'm currently using is the `cv2.matchTemplate()` from openCV, the problem is that this method only compare shapes, not colors. In the mentioned game there are a lot of similar shapes, and the biggest difference is the color. So i wondered what method / function i should use for this.

Sorry for poor grammar, english is not my native language.

[image: Image captured and cropped from the game]
[image: Default Image]
Method to crop around Image:

```
def crop_image(image_path):
sprite = cv2.imread(image_path)

sprite_resized = cv2.resize(sprite,(0,0),fx=10,fy=10) # resize for visualisation purposes

sprite_gray  = cv2.cvtColor(sprite_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sprite_canny = cv2.Canny(sprite_gray, 60,30,3,3) # <- play around with these params.
sprite_canny = sprite_canny.astype(np.bool) # is now a masked array

# because sprite_canny is a masked array, we can change the pixels in the sprite_resized
# to a different color to display the result. here the canny edges are shown in red
sprite_resized[sprite_canny] = (0,0,255)

# clever part: get the ranges of the bounding x and y coordinates. for this, we can use
# .any(axis = 0 or 1) to check if there's a point along the x or y axis. read as: "any
# point along axis 0 or 1?"
mx = sprite_canny.any(axis = 0)
my = sprite_canny.any(axis = 1)

# with this, we can get the range of x and y coordinate and get the min and max from them.
# to calculate the range, we need the width and height in pixels, accessed using .shape
h, w = sprite_gray.shape
rx = np.arange(w)[mx]
ry = np.arange(h)[my]

x_min = np.min(rx)
y_min = np.min(ry)

x_max = np.max(rx)
y_max = np.max(ry)
#COMMENT OUT RETURN TOO SE DEFAULT SCRIPT
return cv2.resize(sprite_gray[y_min:y_max, x_min:x_max], IMAGE_SIZE)
# use these coordinates to display a green rectangle around the found sprite
cv2.rectangle(sprite_resized, (x_min,y_min), (x_max,y_max), (0,255,0), 2)
```

Method to compare images:

```
def compare_images(image, library):
value = 0
max_value = 0
compared_image = str()

for file in os.listdir(library):
    template = f'{library}\\{file}'
    try:
        template = crop_image(template)
        value = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, method=cv2.TM_CCOEFF)[0][0]
    except Exception: pass

    if value > max_value:
        max_value = value
        compared_image = file
return max_value, compared_image
```

Comment: You can use 3 channel images with matchTemplate(). See the documentation. It compares each channel and then computes an "average" score from the 3 channels. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be where it says "In case of a color image, template summation in the numerator and each sum in the denominator is done over all of the channels and separate mean values are used for each channel. That is, the function can take a color template and a color image. The result will still be a single-channel image, which is easier to analyze."